# Using the state hook to count inside of promises

Tags: reactjs, react-native, typeorm

I am back with a newbie question, eventually i have built a function too complex with my promises, but maybe someone has some insight in why the setSiteAdded/Updated and setArticlesAdded/Updated functions are not working in the correct way for me here. I want to count up, all directly saved and updated elements of the fetched data from my API.

I am using typeORM locally on my ios device with sqlite.

Here is my code:

```js
const saveToDB = (type, element) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (type === 'site') {
        let site = new Site();

        site.created = element.CREATED;
        site.sitenum = element.SITENUM;
        site.title = element.TITLE;
        site.updated = element.UPDATED;

        let siteRepository = getRepository(Site);

        siteRepository.findOne({ where: { sitenum: site.sitenum } })
          .then((foundSite) => {
            site.id = foundSite.id;
            if (foundSite.updated !== site.updated) {
              siteRepository.update(foundSite.id, site)
              .then((savedSite) => {
                console.log("Site has been updated!", savedSite);
                setSitesUpdated(sitesUpdated + 1);
                resolve(savedSite);
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error: ", error);
                reject();
              });
            } else {
              resolve();
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            siteRepository.save(site)
            .then((savedSite) => {
              console.log("Site has been saved!", savedSite);
              setSitesAdded(sitesAdded + 1);
              resolve(savedSite);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Error: ", error);
              reject();
            });
          });
      } else if (type === 'article') {
        let article = new Article();

        article.created = element.CREATED;
        article.updated = element.UPDATED;
        article.artnum = element.ARTNUM;
        article.ean = element.EAN;
        article.title1 = element.TITLE1;
        article.title2 = element.TITLE2;
        article.unit = element.UNIT;
        article.price = element.PRICE;
        article.quantity = element.QUANTITY;

        let articleRepository = getRepository(Article);

        articleRepository.findOne({ where: { artnum: article.artnum } })
          .then((foundArticle) => {
            article.id = foundArticle.id;
            if (foundArticle.updated !== article.updated) {
              articleRepository.update(foundArticle.id, article)
              .then((savedArticle) => {
                console.log("Article has been updated!", savedArticle);
                setArticlesUpdated(articlesUpdated + 1);
                resolve(savedArticle);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error: ", error);
                reject();
              });
            } else {
              resolve();
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            articleRepository.save(article)
            .then((savedArticle) => {
              console.log("Article has been saved!", savedArticle);
              setArticlesAdded(articlesAdded + 1);
              resolve(savedArticle);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Error: ", error);
              reject();
            });
          });
      }
    })
  }

  const fetchDataFromServer = () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      setLoading(true);
      Promise.all([
        new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          let counter = 0;
          let sites = await fetch(
            host + 'sites', { method: 'GET', headers: { token: token } }
          )
          let sitesJson = await sites.json();

          Promise.all(sitesJson.data.map(async (element) => {
            counter++;
            return saveToDB('site', element)
          }))
          .then(() => {
            setSitesAdded(counter);
            resolve();
          })
          .catch(() => reject());
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }),
      new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          let articles = await fetch(
            host + 'articles', { method: 'GET', headers: { token: token } }
          )
          let articlesJson = await articles.json();

          Promise.all(articlesJson.data.map(async (element) => {
            return saveToDB('article', element)
          }))
          .then(() => resolve())
          .catch(() => reject());
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      })
    ])
    .then(() => resolve())
    .catch(() => reject())
    })
  }
```